# How to make a relation of same table in JPA?

Tags: jpa, tree

Need make a relationship between same table. Example: the object "category" have subcategories and the subcategorie have other subcategorie.

In MySQL make a column and point to primary key of same table, but, howto make in JPA?

My code is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "objects")
public class JObject {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private JObject parentJObject;
    private Set<JObject> jObjects;

    public JObject(){
    }

    public JObject(long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public JObject(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public JObject(String name, JObject parentJObject){
        this.name = name;
        this.parentJObject = parentJObject;
    }

    @Null
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public JObject getParentJObject() {
        return parentJObject;
    }

    public void setParentJObject(JObject parentJObject) {
        this.parentJObject = parentJObject;
    }

    @Null
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentJObject", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<JObject> getJObjects() {
        return jObjects;
    }

    public void setJObjects(Set<JObject> jObjects) {
        this.jObjects = jObjects;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }     
}
```

And the making objects:

```
JObject jObjectcategories = new JObject("Demo 1");
Set categoriesJObjects = new HashSet<JObject>(){{
    add(new JObject("Demo 1.1", jObjectcategories));
}};
jObjectcategories.setJObjects(categoriesJObjects);

jObjectDao.save(new HashSet<JObject>() {{
    add(jObjectcategories);
}});
```

But does not works. The log says:

> List of constraint violations:[ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='It has to be null', propertyPath=JObjects, rootBeanClass=class a.b.c.models.JObject, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Null.message}'} ]

Answer (score 0):

You need to be consistent in where you place your JPA annotations: either all on fields, or all on getters. But not mixed as you're doing.

The OneToOne should be a ManyToOne according to your description, since several objects share the same parent.

And the cascade ALL doesn't make sense: you don't want to delete a parent when a child is deleted.

Comment: Thanks, i set the anotation in variable, not the function. Works fine.

Comment: works fine but does not save the relations. I found this: https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/ y try migrate these functions to one only object but does not works. Updated the main post.